# Turn volume/vibration off for SMS

Tags: android

Is there a way, programmatically, to turn the volume and vibration off for the default SMS app so that it does not ring/vibrate when SMS is received?

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe so; not just for the SMS app, that is. On pre-KitKat versions, you might be able to intercept and abort the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast before the native app gets it. Starting with KitKat, though, there's no way to disable the default SMS app from receiving incoming SMS, as they receive a specific broadcast no other app does. It's possible for the user to uncheck the "Show notifications" option for the default app in Settings, but the SDK has no methods to even read that option, let alone set it. I'm not sure if this has changed with Lollipop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

//To made it as silent,

```
AudioManager aM = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        aM.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

//To made it as Vibrate

```
aM.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
```